# How to Set expiration time for Session cookie in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

How to set the expiration time for session cookie in PHP?
I'm setting the session in index page which can be visited multiple time and the problem is this continuously resets the expiration time which I don't need.

How to use the [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) properly in the index page which is visited multiple times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Try the ini option
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

You can also try setting from the script using session_set_cookie_params(lifetimeinsecs)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: @nice_dev Partially it solves the ans, but I hope there is something in built in PHP for the purpose than checking and destroying sessions.

Comment: @PranJoseph I don't have access to ini file in shared hosting package.

Comment: @www.friend0.in Sure is but you don't have access as you said.